# How can useUser() in the Auth0 nextjs-auth0 library lookup a user without reading cookies?

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, auth0

[Auth0's useUser()](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/src/client/use-user.tsx) attempts to fetch a logged in user from `/api/auth/me`, which calls `handleAuth()`, which initiates Auth0 (creates `sessionCache` instance, etc.) and calls [profileHandler(req, res)](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/src/handlers/profile.ts).

In the `profileHandler`, we see a call to `sessionCache.isAuthenticated(req, res)`, which in turn checks the `sessionCache` instance for a previous session entry (key: req object, value: Encrypted object containing user info, access_token, id_token, etc.).

Since each API call, i.e. each call of `handleAuth()`, whether from `/api/auth/me`, `/api/auth/login`, or otherwise, is a separate serverless function call, will `profileHandler` (`/api/auth/me`) really ever find an entry in the sessionCache?

I know we add an entry there at login (in `callbackHandler`), but I do not understand how that cache value persists between two separate Serverless Function calls.

nextjs-auth0 states in the docs:

> By default, the session is stateless and stored in an encrypted
> cookie. But if you want a stateful session you can provide a store
> with `get`, `set` and `destroy` methods to store the session on the
> server.

So, we know it is stateless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand how that cache value persists between two separate Serverless Function calls.

The session is stored in a cookie and every separate Serverless Function call reads that cookie and populates the `sessionCache` (which stores the session in a WeakMap per request). The `sessionCache` is just there to make sure you can access the session multiple times during the lifecycle of a single request without having to read/decrypt the cookie every time.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that is actually what I expected, but I could not find the place in the code where useUser() reads the cookie. `checkSession()` in useUser() -> API call to *api/auth/me* -> runs `handleProfile()` -> Runs `sessionCache.isAuthenticated` from cache.js (https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/1de5e1856e2847d0492ba51fc93681b223cb7ae8/src/session/cache.ts#L46). Cookies are not read anywhere there. I am probably just missing it, a pointer would be really helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: `sessionCache.isAuthenticated` -> `sessionCache.init` -> `sessionStore.read` (which reads the cookie)

Comment: Thanks a million, can't believe I missed that...